# "Your company name" or "Your company's name"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Which way is correct here? Some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is 'here'?

Comment: @TimLymington - In the title. I admit I should've placed it in the main body of the question, too. But I am so lazy these days... If you have the right of editing questions, feel free to do it.

Comment: Actually, I meant "both can be correct in certain circumstances; could you give us a clue about where you want to use it?"

Comment: @TimLymington - "both can be correct in certain circumstances" - Oh really?! I didn't know that. I thought only one was correct, so my intended scope of usage would encompass just about any possible situation, in which English is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Company name" is a noun phrase that is used on legal papers and other forms when dealing with a company as an artificial person or [legal entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation). Typically in these cases, "your" would not precede "company name" because the legally company represents itself.

This phrase is used in correspondence between the company and another legal entity.

"Your company's name" is an informal phrase which means "the name of the company that you own (in part or in full)" or possibly "the name of the company that employees you".

This phrase is used in conversations among real people.

Comment: What about a questionnaire that is given to some owners of their companies when a certain poll is being made? Would it be a formal or informal case? Should it be written "Your company name:  ________" or "Your company's name:  ___________" in that questionnaire?

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with this answer. The first form of "your company name" is in the possessive and is in reference to the company you own where "your company's name" may be a reference to the company you work for and not necessarily one that you own.

Comment: Are you using *employee* as a verb?

Comment: Apparently, he can use "employees" to mean "makes into an employee".

Comment: What phrases are used in conversations among unreal people?