# the company failure to comply vs the company's failure

Tags: possessives, noun-phrases

I got into an argument with a British native speaker over the following phrase:

*'the company failure to comply with its contractual obligations'*

I'm a non-native speaker, therefore I can't be quite sure, but I really doubt this could be grammatically correct.

Am I wrong, are both 'company failure' and 'company's failure' correct? Context: website article for a law firm.

The whole sentence:

It is necessary to determine or at least assess the amount of damage, which may be caused by ***a Ukrainian company failure to comply*** with its contractual obligations.

Some other cases:

It is necessary to determine or at least assess the amount of damage, which may be caused by ***a Ukrainian partner failure to comply*** with an agreement.

An important factor is the possible introduction of legislative currency restrictions that may affect ***the Ukrainian company ability*** to buy foreign currency and transfer it to a foreign counterparty.

Such enforcement proceedings may signal the commencement of ***the counterparty’s financial problems***.

Meanwhile, ***the company winding-up*** is possible through its reorganization or liquidation.

In the latter case, the Ukrainian law provides for a period within which ***Ukrainian counterparty creditors*** may file their claims against such a bankrupt company.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Your company name" or "Your company's name"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/your-company-name-or-your-companys-name) See also [A noun adjunct / the possessive case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87591/a-noun-adjunct-the-possessive-case) specifically asking about *the **shop** door / the **shop’s** door*.

Comment: I can't say either of them quite answers my question. Or maybe I'm just not getting it, sorry.

Comment: You need to include the complete sentence. Imagine someone asking "Is _boys' hands_ or _boy's hands_ correct?" But does this answer your question? [Why do we say a “hotel room” and not a “hotel's room”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room)

Comment: I thought 'the company failure to comply with its contractual obligations' should be enough, it's not like I asked is 'company failure correct'. The sentences are long, there were several similar cases in one text, I've now added them to the question body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I** According to [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=company+failure%2Ccompany%27s+failure&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompany%20failure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompany%20%27s%20failure%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccompany%20failure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompany%20's%20failure%3B%2Cc0) both are used and "company's failure" is much more common. "Company's failure" refers to a particular failure in a given domain of operation of a company (1) or to a case of company failure (2) as this is defined in "**II**", in other words  a commercial failure ending the company.

- (1) When "(1)" is the case, the noun phrase has a complement introduced by "to" which makes precise the given failure.: "*the/a company's failure to comply…*", "*the/a company's failure to pay…*", "*the company's failure to provide information…*", etc.
- (2) [Traders, Planters and Slaves: Market Behavior in Early …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kZyQLbKJwJkC&pg=PA150&dq=%22company%27s+failure%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipgKD5mInpAhUBxoUKHf8AAroQ6AEIhQEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22company's%20failure%22&f=false)
  David W. Galenson - 2002 -
  Any one of these problems by itself might have been sufficient to cause the company's failure; the presence of all three appears to have ensured it. Interestingly, the poor economic performance of the Royal African Company may have ...

**II** "Company failure" is a compound noun which the term "business failure" connotes; but here is a source which defines implicitly "company failure" as "commercial failure": [commercial failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure#Commercial_failures). In all cases one might also use the term "flop".

[Turning Around Failing Schools: Leadership Lessons From the …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=v0lOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22company+failure%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTvr3DlonpAhWIHhQKHbv4ClgQ6AEI-wEwFQ#v=onepage&q=%22company%20failure%22&f=false)
Joseph Murphy, ‎Coby V. Meyers - 2007 -
—“the study of the symptoms of company failure has been a most neglected area of management” (Argenti, 1976, p. 57).

[Company Law in the New Europe: The EU Acquis, Comparative …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SxUM_jiTWy8C&pg=PA138&dq=%22company+failure%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTvr3DlonpAhWIHhQKHbv4ClgQ6AEI7gEwFA#v=onepage&q=%22company%20failure%22&f=false)
Janet Dine, ‎Marios Koutsias, ‎Michael Blecher - 2007 - ‎
However the risks to shareholders and the risks to employees are significantly different if we look at the impact of a company failure. The shareholders are carefully protected by the state imposition of limited liability and if the company fails will ..

---

According to the grammar of the examined sentence there is little doubt that it must be "company's failure" as meaning "failure in a particular domain (not the end of the business). It is the failure to comply to some requirement, necessity, legal injunction, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much! You made it very clear! 
My simple logic was as follows: in this case it's not 'company failure' (=business failure), it's a failure to comply. Whose failure to comply -- the company's failure to comply.